# How to convert encoded unicode to readable unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, ascii, encode

I'm so lost on this topic that I don't even know how to properly phrase my question.

I have a bunch of weird escape delimited codes within unicode in python. I want to make it human readable. I believe that it must be once again be in unicode format because there are characters unrepresentable in ascii. How can I do this? There are simply too many things online like encode, decode, str, codec, etc etc that i'm not sure what to do anymore.

Thank you.

```
u"\u202e\u062c\u0647\u0627\u0646\u202c - \u202dBBC     
\u202e\u0641\u0627\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u202c - 
\u202e\u0646\u0634\u0633\u062a '\u062f"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you've got your hands on some Persian!

```
>>> foo = u"\u202e\u062c\u0647\u0627\u0646\u202c - \u202dBBC  \u202e\u0641\u0627\u0631\u0633\u06cc\u202c - \u202e\u0646\u0634\u0633\u062a
>>> print foo        
جهان‬ - ‭BBC  ‮فارسی‬ - ‮نشست 'د
```

Stackoverflow's codeblock feature doesn't seem to like a combination of left-/right-aligned text very well, so here's a screenshot aswell:

[image: Persian unicode output]

It seems to be something about BBC World Persian (Iran). Atleast that's what [Google translate indicates](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D8%AC%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86%E2%80%AC%20-%20%E2%80%ADBBC%20%20%E2%80%AE%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C%E2%80%AC%20-%20%E2%80%AE%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B3%D8%AA%20%27%D8%AF). It is horribly hard to get the order right because of broken selection, but the language seems to fit.

Comment: Thanks but I have one additional question. I need the converted unicode stored in memory because it has to be sent over to an html template. The print method converts it fine but is there a way I can convert the code then store it in some variable, where I can send it over?

Comment: @LucasOu-Yang I'm not sure how you would do that. But atleast it seems to be possible to store special characters in a string, or atleast some of them. http://bpaste.net/show/wauSKEUlBgdxEu5aFPBF/